# Finding which file includes iostream in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, header-files

We are converting our code to use a logging library rather than `std::cout` and, as part of that, we simply remove `#include <iostream>` from each source file as we go. This *should* allow us to easily identify the lines that still use `cout` (since they'll have compilation errors) and fix them quickly.

However, many of the files still work even with the `#include` removed, meaning that some other header it uses is probably including it. Since we have a great *many* headers in a rather large hierarchy, is there a way to get Visual Studio to actually tell us which header file is including `iostream` and where it sits in the hierarchy.

I know I could simply search the lot of them but I'm only interested in those that are actually bought in to a *specific* source file. Because we're doing this bit by bit, it's unworkable to change every single file in one go.

I've been putting `#define cout JUNK` at the top of files to date so as to cause errors with using `cout` for output but I want to remove all `iostream` stuff from the files if possible.

Comment: Use a mock `<iostream>` that causes error?

Comment: I've often used the `GNU` compiler's [`-H`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-7.3.0/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html#Preprocessor-Options) flag to inspect the `#include` hierarchy.  I'd assume Visual Studio has something similar that might be of use -- [/showincludes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hdkef6tk.aspx)?

Comment: How about using unix command "grep" on powershell? You can also put "content: cout" in the search editbox on top right corner of windows explorer.

Comment: Other standard library headers may be including `<iostream>` so there may be no practical solution to your problem.

Comment: I would find what include guard the `iostream` header uses and try defining that (and then removing the definition once you find everything)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you right-click on the file in the `Solution Explorer` and select `Properties`, the `Advanced` tab has a `Show Includes` option:

[image]

Setting this to yes will cause the compiler to output the entire hierarchy of include files, such as:

```
1> FileA.cpp
1> Note: including file: d:\repo\FileA.h
1> Note: including file:  d:\repo\SomeOtherHeader.h
1> Note: including file: d:\repo\FileB.h
1> Note: including file:  d:\repo\YetAntherHeader.h
1> Note: including file:   C:\ProgFiles_x86\MSVS14\VC\include\iostream
```

You can simply copy and past that from the output window into your favorite editor and search for the specific header file you're interested in.